# Where is the Android.mk file for StagefrightRecorder.so

Tags: android, android-source, stagefright, android.mk

I am using Android 4.4.2 source code.

After I compile the source code, I notice there is `StagefrightRecorder.so` file in the out folder. I am studying `StagefrightRecorder.cpp` now, and I am planing to rewrite it. So I wonder where is the `Android.mk` file for `StagefrightRecorder.so`.(I am not familiar with the source code, so I think the `Android.mk` might help.)

Both of the `StagefrightRecorder.cpp` and `StagefrightRecorder.h` are in the folder `frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice`. There is one `Android`.mk file in that folder, but that one is used to create `libmediaplayerservice` module, and it calls `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` `StagefrightRecorder`.

Does anyone know this? Thank you!

Comment: I feel you are viewing a customized version of `AOSP`. The standard build doesn't build a `StagefrightRecorder.so` as a separate library. `StagefrightRecorder` is part of `libmediaplayerservice.so` as can be seen here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/Android.mk#23 .

Comment: @Ganesh Yeah, I found that one. But check that one, there is 'LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstagefright' in that file. So it calls libstagefright.so, is it?

Comment: When `StagefrightRecorder` invokes `MediaRecorder` which internally creates `CameraSource`, `OMXCodec`, `MPEG4Writer` / any of the `MediaWriter`s, `libstagefright.so` would be involved and hence, there is a dependency between `libmediaplayerservice` and `libstagefright`